# Real time sync of Core Data between WatchKit and the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, watchkit

I am writing a WatchKit extension for an iPhone application. I share Core Data using App Groups. This is working, the data is shared. Now I want to refresh data inside the iPhone app if the app is running in the foreground and a new database entry is added from the watch to the database. To track that I subscribed to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:nil];
        }
    }
```

merge method:

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if(notification.object != self.managedObjectContext) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateMainContext:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

update main context method:

```
- (void)updateMainContext:(NSNotification *)notification {
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

I am trying to test it on the simulator (by running the iPhone and Watch simulator simultaneously) , but unfortunately `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` is not called.

Is it actually possible to test it on the simulator? If yes, is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use NSNotificationCenter since the iOS app and extension are different processes.  Look at using MMWormhole to post your own notifications between the processes.  You can listen for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` in your extension and iOS app and then use MMWormhole to let the other process know about the notification.  Also, you will need to manually refresh your managed data objects (See `[NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:(NSManagedObject *)object mergeChanges:(BOOL)flag]`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was under impression that if the app and the watch are using the same NSPersistentStore (sqlite file), then I would be able to track changes in it. Am I wrong? I thought it would be something similar as working with multiple contexts on different threads.

Comment: Because the WatchKit extension and the iOS app run in different process they do not communicate with each other.  When you have two threads running in the same process they can communicate with each other.  So you have to manage the communication.  I added it to my WatchKit extension and it doesn't require too much extra work.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure this SHOULD work. You can use Notification Center to listen to things within the WatchKit extension, and what he is trying to listen to is a NSManagedObjectContext that was set up from within the WatchKit app that is attached to a persistent store that is shared between the apps using app groups. Or am I missing something here? I have my watchkit app listening to shared database changes using NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: I thought he was trying to listen for changes made to the persistent store in the iOS app in his WatchKit extension.  Yes, you can have your extension listen for changes made in the extension.

Comment: Hmm but I guess what I meant was this: Suppose you have a persistent store that is shared between the phone and extension, and you have a CoreData stack set up on your extension that is hooked up to that persistent store. Now your iPhone makes changes to this store, the CoreData stack on your watch extension should react to them, right?

Comment: When you say your iPhone makes changes to this store you need to specify if it is the WatchKit extension running on the iPhone or the iPhone app running on the iPhone.  Both processes run on the iPhone.  They can't communicate with NSNotificationCenter since they are different processes.

Comment: @StephenJohnson How to refresh managed object context (on the phone) so it gets newly created (on the watch)  NSManagedObject? refreshObject will only refresh existing object. Thanks.

Comment: I set the stalenessInterval on the NSManagedObjectContext to 1 and I haven't had any problems with my queries getting get out date data.